# Breaking down a date range into multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

Let's say I have a table as follows (multiple projects with multiple date ranges):

```
Project | Start_Date | End_Date
ABC123    10/19/2018     12/31/2018
```

Is there a way to query this into a result set that looks like the following?:

```
Project | Start_Date | End_Date
ABC123    10/19/18     10/31/18
ABC123    11/01/18     11/30/18
ABC123    12/01/18     12/31/18
```

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Comment: T-SQL (Transact-SQL) and Using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Comment: what date format is that?

Comment: Clarify the logic for breaking the data into multiple rows.

Comment: So it seems that you want to break down a single date range (spanning multiple month) into multiple date ranges that spans only one month ... so a date from 2018-10-19 to 2018-12-31 (this is from October to December) should be split into three date ranges October, November and December. And the lower (and upper) boundary should be reflected in the first (and last) month. Right? Just to clarify your question ...

Answer (score 0):

This might need more optimization but giving output as expected as of now

```
 WITH TEMP1 (PROJECT,START_DATE , END_DATE, DT) AS                   
(                                                      
  SELECT PROJECT,START_DATE 
        ,END_DATE
        ,START_DATE DT              
    FROM MYTABLE
   UNION ALL                                          
  SELECT PROJECT
        ,START_DATE 
        ,END_DATE
        ,DATEADD(DAY, 1, DT) DT            
    FROM TEMP1                                           
   WHERE DT < END_DATE                                    
)                  
,TEMP2 AS(
  SELECT PROJECT
        ,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, DT), 0) STARTDATE 
        ,EOMONTH(DT ) ENDDATE                                            
    FROM TEMP1
   GROUP BY PROJECT
           ,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, DT), 0)  
           ,EOMONTH(DT ) 
)

SELECT B.PROJECT
      ,CASE WHEN B.STARTDATE < A.START_DATE THEN A.START_DATE 
            ELSE B.STARTDATE END AS STARTDATEFINAL
      ,CASE WHEN B.ENDDATE > A.END_DATE THEN A.END_DATE 
            ELSE B.ENDDATE END AS ENDDATEFINAL
  FROM MYTABLE A, TEMP2 B
 WHERE A.PROJECT = B.PROJECT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select project, start_date, eomonth(start_date) as end_date, end_date as final_date
      from t
      union all
      select project, dateadd(day, 1, end_date), eomonth(dateadd(day, 1, end_date)), final_date
      from cte
      where end_date < final_date
     )
select project_start_date, end_date
from cte;
```

Note that your question is a bit ambiguous about a couple of things.  Notably, this assumes:

- The end date is not in the same month as the start date.
- The end date is always at the end of the month (or equivalently, you always want the end of the month for the last record).

These are consistent with your sample data.  It is pretty easy to modify the query to handle these, using conditional logic.

EDIT:

For the conditions in the comment:

```
with cte as (
      select project, start_date,
             (case when end_date < eomonth(start_date) then end_date
                   else eomonth(start_date)
              end) as end_date,
             end_date an final_date
      from t
      union all
      select project, start_date,
             (case when end_date < eomonth(start_date) then end_date
                   else eomonth(start_date)
              end) as end_date,
             end_date as final_date
      from t
      union all
      select project, dateadd(day, 1, end_date),
             (case when final_date < eomonth(dateadd(day, 1, end_date))
                   then final_date
                   else eomonth(dateadd(day, 1, end_date))
              end), final_date
      from cte
      where end_date < final_date
     )
select project_start_date, end_date
from cte;
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2a50d2014d240aacf6d9904b997314f3).

Comment: I went by the assumption that he wants to break the dates among months. So if end date is last date its fine otherwise last row should have that date as end date and not the last date

Comment: Thank you all for your help! There are cases where projects can end in the same month as when it starts. So if Project123 spans from 10/19/18 to 10/31/18, I would need the result to show just 1 line with dates 10/19/18-10/31/18. Additionally the end date may not always be the last day of the month. So if the project spans from 10/15/18-11/15/18 there would need to be two lines: 1 for 10/15/18-10/31/18 and 11/1/18-11/15/18.

Comment: @JJL . . . You should add the examples to your *question*.

Comment: @JJL . . . I added a db<>fiddle and fixed up the code.